# Can I configure a Redstone Energy Cell to emit a redstone signal if it is full?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have [Magmatic Engines](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Magmatic_Engine) powering a [Redstone Energy Cell](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Redstone_Energy_Cell). Is there a way to configure the cell to emit a redstone signal once it's full, so I can use said signal to rurn off my engines so they dont waste lava?

Comment: I think there is let me do some testing and get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing you can. For this you will need:

- Cobblestone Structure Pipe
- Gate

Put the Pipe next to the Energy Cell and place the Gate on it. Right click on the Gate and choose Full Energy = Redstone Signal. Lead Redstone to the engine. Make sure it has redstone control on it. Here's some screen shots. To Cell wasn't full thus no redstone signal thus the engine could run goodluck.

[image: overview]

[image: Gate Conditionals]

[image: Redstone Control]

Comment: Well done! I know nothing about gates yet so this answer was beyond me, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

In later versions of Minecraft and Thermal Expansion, Energy Cells work with the standard [Redstone Comparator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_comparator). Put down a Comparator next to an Energy Cell, with the comparator pointing away from the cell, and it will emit a redstone signal level (~ 0-15) proportional to how full the cell is.